# Unable to curl from command line

Tags: bash, unix, curl, wget

Maybe a very naive question.. Lets say I have a url

```
http://localhost:8088/querty?q=r8
```

I am able to access the above url from  my browser but when I do wget or curl

say  `curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "http://localhost:8088`
gives 000

```
wget "http://localhost:8088/querty?q=r8"
```

gives

```
--2014-08-19 15:55:03--  (try: 7)  http://localhost:8088/querty?q=r8
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

I see no response

Not able to understand whats happening?

Edit:

```
Response from verbose flag:
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f8ad3804400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f8ad3804400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to localhost port 8088 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8088 (#0)
> HEAD /querty?q=r8 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8088
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Worth trying -- what happens if you change "silent" to "verbose" in the curl? `curl -o /dev/null --verbose --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "http://localhost:8088"` ... might be worth updating your description with that output instead of the silent curl repro.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn: Pasted the response

Comment: What happens if you try a normal `GET` request and not a `HEAD` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a response, just with no data in the response. (That is, 'empty response' as opposed to 'no response'.)

Googling for `curl 52 empty reply from server` and `wget "no data received"` yields a variety of threads containing various reasons why this may occur -- which is to say, from the data so far, I don't believe a clear-cut root cause is identifiable yet.

One repro, for instance, is on a server where adding `--header="accept-encoding: gzip"` to the `wget` request was the solution -- that may fit your scenario, since a browser would presumably add such a header, whereas manual `curl` and `wget` attempts would not.

Another idea (which I use myself in similar debugging situations) is to use `lynx` -- it's a terminal browser, which comes with some extra browser-like behavior that's sometimes harder to achieve via `curl` or `wget`. (Such as interpreting relative href links in the context of the page's URL -- granted, that's not relevant here, but you get the idea.) So that would look like `lynx -source "http://localhost:8088"`.